# алгоритм z-функции

Tags: python-3.x, строки

Вот пример поиска z-функции:

Пусть `s=«abacaba»`(вводится)

- `z[0]` = 0 — по определению
- `z[1]` = 0 — ищем длину наидл. общего    префикса у abacaba и `bacaba:bacaba` начинается с `b`,поэтому `z[1]=0`
- `z[2]` = 1 — ищем ДНОП у `abacaba` и `acaba`
- `z[3]` = 0 — ищем ДНОП у    `abacaba` и `caba`
- `z[4]` = 3 — ищем ДНОП у `abacaba` и `aba;abacaba`
- `z[5]` = 0 — ищем ДНОП у `abacaba` и `ba`
- `z[6]` = 1 — ищем ДНОП у `abacaba` и `a` где ДНОП-длина наибольшего общего префикса

  ```
  z = input()
  y=list(z)
  k=0
  for i in range(0,len(y)):
    for x in range(1,len(y)):
      x=0
      if y[i+x]==y[x]:
          k+=1
      x+=1
  print(k)
  ```

Comment: И? Вы что-то хотели спросить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def z(string, idx):
    if not idx : return 0
    i=0
    for a,b in zip(string, string[idx:]):
        if not a == b :
            break
        i+=1
    return i

for i in range(len('abacaba')) :
    print(z('abacaba', i))

# 0 0 1 0 3 0 1
```

Comment: и код поподробнее объяснить

Comment: давайте, вы спросите, что непонятно

Comment: s = input(); for i in range(len(s)) :     print(z(s, i))

Comment: ввод можно, я просто только щас понял что idx не переменная

Comment: впринципе всё понять можно

Comment: http://pythonicway.com/python-functinal-programming#zip

Comment: idx - переменная, аргумент функции - с какого отступа считать

Comment: 'if not idx : return 0' объясните пожалуйста что это делает;string[idx:]-что означает двоеточие, и каким типом является idx в этом случае

Comment: z[0] = 0 — по определению. если не проверить, что задан 0, то результатом будет длина слова. Про string[idx:] - почитайте по ключевым словам python slices. В данном случае возвращает часть строки от индекса idx до конца